Are "Where is x in the source code" questions beneficial?
A user recently asked Where is the code that receives blocks that miners have just solved. I see these kind of questions often and the answer can be found by just using Github's code search feature most of the time on the Bitcoin repo and even alt coin repos. Are these kind of questions useful on stack exchange or are they off-topic?

I think so, why not?

I would suggest that for a user unfamiliar with C++, and even with the codebase in question, it is kind of a stretch to ask them to use code search to find something when they don't have any idea what the code might look like.
But I also question the user's motives in asking this - if the user is not a programmer, what problem are they actually trying to solve? Is this an XY problem? Is it just an attempted learning exercise where the user dives headlong into the nearest interesting open source codebase?
I am actually leaning toward on-topic here. The question:

is relevant to Bitcoin
is objective
has a correct answer
could certainly be useful to a skilled programmer intending to modify the code in some way

If such questions are repeated frequently, they are of course ripe for collection into a duplicate graph.
